# Plot a complex function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Could you please help me figure out how I can get a figure of the following function?

```
 (y - x^2)(2x^2 - y) >= 0
```

x >= 0

Comment: Your inequality produces a [region](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%28y+-+x%5E2%29%282x%5E2+-+y%29+%3E%3D+0%2C+x+%3E%3D+0%7D).

Comment: reduce the equation first

Comment: @rickhg12hs I need a shape in Matlab.

Comment: @GAlexander Reducing the equation also does not give an admirable function. Again it is a complex one.

Comment: this function is not complex. reduce/transform the equation.

Comment: @GAlexander So, how I can plot x^2 =< y <= 2x^2 in Matlab?

Comment: Plotting this in Matlab/Octave could be done by solving the inequalities for `y` and then using `area` to plot the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve that plot in MATLAB, simply define a [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of coordinates and limiting the range of the `x` and `y` values to some predetermined limits.  You'd simply substitute each pair of `x` and `y` values in the above equation and plot a map that tells you which values of `x` and `y` satisfy that inequality.

Something like this:

```
xmax = 5; ymax = 5; step_size = 0.01;
xval = -xmax:step_size:xmax;
yval = -ymax:step_size:ymax;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-xmax:step_size:xmax, -ymax:step_size:ymax);
z = ((y - x.^2).*(2*x.^2 - y) >= 0) & (x >= 0);
figure; 
imagesc(z); colormap gray; shading interp; axis xy;
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', xval(101:100:end));
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', yval(101:100:end));
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
```

The first line establishes the boundaries of the `x` and `y` values that you want to plot as well as the step size in between successive `x` or `y` values.  The next line defines a grid of 2D coordinates that span the space defined by the first line of code.  I'm assuming a symmetric range going from `-N` to `N` for both coordinates.  The line after that computes a `logical` map that describes the above equation where `false` means that a pair of `x` and `y` values didn't satisfy the equation and `true` means it did.  The last few lines are all for producing the plot.  I use [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) to display this region for us, enforcing that the colour map be gray, the shading be interpolated and `imagesc` makes the `y` axis going downwards as positive by default.  To flip this to what we're used to, I used `axis xy`.

The last part of the code is primarily for clean up.  Because `imagesc` is displaying an image, I'd like the horizontal and vertical axes to display the actual coordinate data rather than the indices of each pair of `x` and `y` values.  As such, I simply relabel the `x` and `y` labels so that they are what we expect and I also give the appropriate titles for each the dimensions.

We get this:

[image]

Here, white means that the pair of `x` and `y` coordinates you are looking at satisfy the inequality and black means that the pair didn't.

Answer (score 0):

reformat equation
z = 2x^4 - 3x^2y +y^2

[image: 3d mesh]
[image: countour]